# Passing object to method laravel php bundles

Tags: php, object, parameter-passing, laravel, laravel-3

Probably a noob question but here we go.

I'm using laravel and the messages bundle to send emails to verify users. But how do I get access to my $new_user object from within my send method?

```
    // Get inputdata and insert into table users
    $new_user = User::create(array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'), 
        'email' => Input::get('email'), 
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
        'hash' => hash('sha512', uniqid()) 
    ));

    Message::send(function($message)
    {
        $message->to('blablabla@hotmail.com');
        $message->from($new_user->email, $new_user->username);

        $message->subject('new account');
        $message->body('

            Bedankt voor het registreren!

            Uw account is aangemaakt, u kan inloggen met de volgende gegevens nadat u u account heeft geactiveerd met de url hier beneden.

            ------------------------
            Username: '.$new_user->username.'
            Password: '.$new_user->password.'
            ------------------------

            Klik op deze link om uw account te activeren.

            http://blablabla.dev/verify?email='.$new_user->email.'&hash='.$new_user->hash.' 

        ');
    });
```

Doing this obviously doesn't work since I don't have access to the object.

Hopefully I've phrased this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `use` keyword here

```
$new_user = User::create(array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'), 
    'email' => Input::get('email'), 
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
    'hash' => hash('sha512', uniqid()) 
));

Message::send(function($message) use ($new_user)
{
    $message->to('blablabla@hotmail.com');
    $message->from($new_user->email, $new_user->username);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$message instanceof Message? and what params should be passed to the Message::send()?
May be you better do this:

```
$message = new Message;
$message->to('blablabla@hotmail.com');
$message->from($new_user->email, $new_user->username);
$message->subject('new account');
$message->body('...'.$new_user->email.'...');
```

If you have public (not static) method send() in your Message class, and it looks like this:

```
public function send(){
     @mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->body, $this->header, $this->params);
}
```

Then do

```
$message->send();
```

Else, if you have only static send() method in your Message class, and it defined as

```
static function send(Message $message){...}
```

call

```
Message::send($message);
```

Also I recommend you to validate user input before adding it to database.